# Value of type ... has no member

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm learning it on iTunes U, using a Stanford University course. I'm programming a calculator. The instructor in the course video has the same code, software and same version of Xcode.

So here's the code for my `ViewController`:

```
@IBAction private func performOperation(sender: UIButton) {
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
        brain.setOperand(displayValue)
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
    }

    if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
        brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
    }

    displayValue = brain.result
}
```

The error is in the last sentence: `displayValue = brain.result`:

> Value of type 'CalculatorBrain' has no value 'result'

This a part of the CalculatorBrain code:

```
struct PendingBinaryOperationInfo {
    var BinaryFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
    var firstOperand: Double }

    var result: Double { get { return 0.0 } }
}
```

So what's the problem?

P.S. All of the calculator functions aren't set to work yet. And the ode that some suggested,

```
 displayValue.text = "\(brain.result)"
```

didn't work at all and it gave me a ton of other errors.

Comment: Are you sure it's defined inside the `CalculatorBrain` class? Could you post a full code of `CalculatorBrain`?

Comment: Also, may I ask what is the type of your brain? Option+click your brain.

Comment: The error message means that `result` is not in the scope of the class  or struct `CalculatorBrain`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a variable `result` declared as a property of a struct `PendingBinaryOperationInfo`. The variable `result` is not a property (at least not shown here) of a type `CalculatorBrain` wherever that may be. Hence the error.

You have:

```
struct PendingBinaryOperationInfo {
    var result: Double
}
```

When it's looking for:

```
class CalculatorBrain { // 'class' is just an example
    var result: Double
}
```

Answer (score 0):

brain class don't have result this member, You need to check brain class is that a have result variable. The result may be private or internal variable so you can not use. It need to change to public member.